# Behavior of syslog handler in Wildfly 8

Tags: jboss, wildfly, syslog

I want to use the syslog handler in Wildfly 8 to send the application logs to logstash (and I know this may not be best practice at the moment).

Does anyone know how the syslog handler acts if the syslog/logstash server is not available?

Is there any buffering (memory, files), does it consume endless resources in a reconnect loop, in short: Does anyone have experience with the syslog handler?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I've been meaning for a while to write a blog post on how to write log messages to logstash. It's not that hard really, just need to add a dependency and a custom-formatter and custom-handler. Maybe I can get to it soon then I'll add the link here.

Comment: As promised here's a link to a blog post about WildFly and the ELK stack http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/25/Wildfly-And-ELK/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syslog-handler will not buffer messages if the socket can't connect. If you use UDP then it will attempt to connect each time. Using TCP it depends on the version of the logmanager. I think with the version in WildFly 8 it will attempt to reconnect, but you'll lose any messages sent while the syslog server is down.